# Closed form expression for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k^2 + 3k + 2)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

How can I find the closed form expression for the sum below using **generating functions**?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(k^2 + 3k + 2)$$

**EDIT:**

We transform $k^2+3k+2$ into $(k+2)(k+1)$. Let $a_k=(k+2)(k+1)$ and $b_k=1$. Then

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)(k+2)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\;,$$

which is the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\right)\;.$$

Because, $b_n = 1$, we get that $\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n = \sum_{n\ge 0}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$. If we differentiate $\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ twice, I will get $\sum_{n\ge 0}n(n-1)x^{n-2} = -\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}$. Then my changing the index, we get $\sum_{n\ge 2}n+2(n+1)x^{n} = -\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}$.

For $\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n = \sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)(n+2)x^n$. Which is, $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\sum_{n\ge 0}x^{n+2})$. And?

Comment: the closed form is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2+3k+2=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{3}$

Comment: @E.H.E And where exactly did you use the generating function, I don't see.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Notice that $k^2+3k+2=(k+2)(k+1)$. Let $a_k=(k+2)(k+1)$ and $b_k=1$. Then

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)(k+2)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\;,$$

which is the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\right)\;.$$

To get the generating function for $\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n$ you can use the observation that $(k+2)(k+1)x^k$ is the second derivative of $x^{k+2}$. Alternatively, if you know the generating function for $\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+2}2x^n$, you can use the fact that $(k+2)(k+1)=2\binom{k+2}2$.

Comment: You included $x^k$, to transform it into a generating function? And how did you get the derivative and the sum on the right hand side from the sum on the left hand side?

Comment: @opsorst: Yes to the first question. For the second question, I did it by inspection: $(k+2)(k+1)x^k$ leaps out at me as the second derivative of $x^{k+2}$.And since I already know how to sum a finite geometric series, I can see that this is a useful observation.

Comment: Yes, now I see, it is the second derivative of $x^{k+2}$. But, now how should I proceed? I only know the form of the generating functions where $A(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n$. This sum doesn't seem to obey this, and I have the derivative in front, which means sooner or later I will need to get out of it.

Comment: @opsorst: $$\sum_{k=0}^nx^{k+2}=x^2\sum_{k=0}^nx^k=x^2\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}x^k-\sum_{k\ge n+1}x^k\right)\;.$$ You know the generating function for the first summation in the parentheses, and the second summation is just $x^{n+1}$ times that.

Comment: So you mean I will have, $x^2 (\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{x^{k+1}}{1-x})$?

Comment: @opsorst: Now quite: the numerator of the second fraction should be $x^{n+1}$.

Comment: Yes, I mistyped it, I was correct when you wrote the comment. So, finally I  have $\frac{x^2}{1-x} - \frac{x^{k+3}}{1-x}$, right? And I should take the second derivative of this?

Comment: @opsorst: Yes, except that you’ve made the same typo.

Comment: I calculated online the second derivative of the fraction, but the result is of course pretty long one, here it is: http://prntscr.com/95ewn7

It's not a pretty fraction at all. And regarding mixing the $k$ and $n$, I guess it is because I didn't exactly understood, how you split the sum like you did in the comment. I mean our original sum went until $n$, and now we have another some that sums after $n+1$, and for it we just get $x^n+1$, I don't see this exactly.

Comment: @opsorst: My hint may have been a little misleading, partly because I kept it very short. Before I expand it, let me ask if you’re familiar with the Cauchy product of two power series.

Comment: Yes, in fact that's what we have been studying lastly, and I'm sure the answer should involve it.

Comment: @opsorst: Excellent. Give me a few minutes to expand and rewrite my answer.

Comment: A few questions, $b_k = 1$, then what is the generating function of a constant, I mean, $\sum_{n\ge 0}1x^k$, is this where $x^{n+1}$ comes from? On the other hand, when you say "use the observation that $(k+2)(k+1)x^k$ is the second derivative of $x^{k+2}$", did we already used it in the comments, and arrived at the bad looking fraction?

Comment: @opsorst: $\sum_{n\ge 0}1x^n=\frac1{1-x}$; that gives you the generating function for the $b_n$s. Now differentiate that equation twice.

Comment: If I differentiate it twice I will get, $-\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}$.

Comment: @opsorst: Differentiate the **equation** twice. You get $$\sum_{n\ge 0}n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\frac2{(1-x)^3}\;.$$ Now rewrite the summation so that the general term is $(n+2)(n+1)x^n$ instead of $n(n-1)x^{n-2}$.

Comment: @opsorst: It’s simpler than that. When $n$ is $0$ or $1$, $n(n-1)x^n=0$, so $$\sum_{n\ge 0}n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\sum_{n\ge 2}n(n-1)x^{n-2}\;.$$ Now let $k=n-2$, and rewrite that last summation with $k$ as the index instead of $n$.

Comment: I can let the sum start from $n \geq 2$?

Comment: @opsorst: Sure: the $n=0$ and $n=1$ terms are both $0$, so dropping them from the sum doesn’t change it.

Comment: I tried to make an edit with the things you told thus far, any idea how to continue?